# how do you quit docker-compose up @ macOS?

Tags: macos, shell, docker, docker-compose

after docker-compose up, on windows i quit that with "CTRL+C" and the container(s) are still running. When i do this on my mac, then docker kills my container :(


I tried it now with a shell script, which executes the docker-compose up into "echo", but on some container, the scripts hang up.


How do you do that? Are there any best practices? (suitable with windows)


Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 32):

If you want to run `docker-compose up` and leave the process running without being attached to your terminal, you can run it in *detached* mode with `docker-compose up -d`.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

After doing so, you'd have to use `docker-compose stop` or `docker-compose down` to stop your running containers, since `CTRL+C` won't kill them.

Comment: ah ok the "-d" flag seems to be fine for this behavior. thanks :)